# LuaInterface/C# - Closures created with .NET objects never get cleaned up

Tags: c#, function, lua, closures, luainterface

I am using the latest version of LuaInterface (http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/) in a C# application. I'm running into a problem where the Lua class is failing to clean up internal references in the ObjectTranslator 'objects' and 'objectsBackMap' dictionaries, resulting in always-growing memory usage.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Lua lua = new Lua();
        string f = @"
            return function(myClass, dotNetObject)
              local f = function() dotNetObject:TestMethod() end
              myClass:StoreFunction(f);
            end";


        var result = lua.DoString(f)[0] as LuaFunction;

        MyClass testItem = new MyClass();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            DotNetObject o = new DotNetObject();
            result.Call(testItem, o);
        }


        lua.DoString("collectgarbage()");
        ObjectTranslator translator = (ObjectTranslator)typeof(Lua).GetField("translator", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(lua);
        Console.WriteLine("Object count: " + translator.objects.Count);
        //Prints out 51. 50 of these items are instances of 'DotNetObject', despite them being unreachable.
        //Forcing a .NET garbage collection does not help. They are still being held onto by the object translator.
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public void StoreFunction(LuaFunction function)
        {
            //I would normally save off the function here to be executed later
        }
    }

    public class DotNetObject
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when the anonymous function (local f = ...) creates a closure involving a .NET object from the outer scope. As long as the Lua interpreter stays alive, 50 instances of the DotNetObject class I've created will never be garbage collected, even when forcing a GC in Lua.

Manually disposing of the LuaFunction (function.Dispose()) object in MyClass.StoreFunction solves the problem, but this is not desirable because in my real application I don't know when the Function will execute--or if it ever will. Forcing me to dispose of the LuaFunction changes the entire architecture of the application such that I'm basically doing manual memory management by disposing the object that contains the LuaFunction, and the object that contains that, all the way up the chain.

So, is this a bug in LuaInterface, or am I using the library incorrectly? Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The essential problem: how does the Lua interpreter know that your C# code isn't going to call the function anymore?  The commented destructor and Dispose() method in LuaFunction.cs suggest this is a problem they've ran into before and don't know how to solve.  Not good.

Comment: Actually, the destructor was just moved to LuaBase, so, the functionality is still there. The Lua interpreter should know that I'm done with the LuaFunction object when it gets finalized. On closer inspection, it looks like the finalize method is calling a version of Dispose which doesn't remove the reference from the interpreter. I'm going to experiment with changing that for LuaFunction.

Comment: You're right.  Look at the destructor though, it doesn't do anything.  The interpreter is only notified when you call Dispose() yourself.

Comment: Ah, you saw that.  Beware that fixing this is difficult, you cannot safely refer to _Interpreter in the destructor.  It might have already been finalized.  An extra flag is needed that says it is dead.